# PHP error: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, wordpress

I updated my Wordpress site from PHP 5.6 to 7.2 and noticed an error in my Wordpress backend after the update. It says:

```
Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements 
Countable in <b>/homepages/36/d362586048/htdocs/genag/wp- 
content/themes/genag- 
theme/framework/admin/functions/functions.mediauploader.php on line 127
```

I have included the code from that line and 2 lines below it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if ( count( $_posts ) ) {
$_id = $_posts->ID;
} else {
```

Comment: accept my edit. your question looks bad without an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_posts` appears to be an object, you should use it like an object `$_posts->ID`. So it cannot be counted like an array.

```
if ( $_posts ) {
```

Should do the job

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 7.2, `count()` method does not support `Null` as a parameter.

I have got the same `error`, in one of my old Avada theme based wordpress website.

I have solved it using the following modification.

```
if ( (!empty($_posts)) && (count( $_posts ) ) { $_id = $_posts->ID; } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

You can use is_countable() function in php to check whether an object supports count functionality.